# SQL Unique Values Numbering Sequence for Pivot

Tags: sql, ms-access, pivot, crosstab

For reporting purcposes, I need to Pivot results of a query that is unique on each record.  My current statement is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales AS x
WHERE (select count(*) from Sales where customer_name=x.customer_name 
        and order_date>=x.order_date)<=5
ORDER BY customer_name, order_date, price;
```

A sample of the Query output is:

```
customer_name    order_date        price
Company A        2009-02-01        800 
Company A        2009-03-01        100
Company A        2009-04-01        200
Company A        2009-05-01        300
Company A        2009-06-01        500
Company B        2009-02-01        100
Company B        2009-02-01        800
Company B        2009-04-01        200
Company B        2009-05-01        300
Company B        2009-06-01        500
```

Ultimately, the information needs to look like this:

```
Customer_Name     order_date1  price1    order_date2  price2    order_date3  price3    order_date4  price4    order_date5  price5   
Company A         2009-02-01   800       2009-03-01   100       2009-04-01   200       2009-05-01   300       2009-06-01   500
Company B         2009-02-01   100       2009-02-01   800       2009-04-01   200       2009-05-01   300       2009-06-01   500
```

I'm thinking that I need to add a column for "pivot_id" so that there is a common record for each grouping so the query result before the pivot will look like:

```
pivot_id  customer_name    order_date        price
1         Company A        2009-02-01        800 
2         Company A        2009-03-01        100
3         Company A        2009-04-01        200
4         Company A        2009-05-01        300
5         Company A        2009-06-01        500
1         Company B        2009-02-01        100
2         Company B        2009-02-01        800
3         Company B        2009-04-01        200
4         Company B        2009-05-01        300
5         Company B        2009-06-01        500
```

What SQL statment will generate an automatic record number for each purchase, but also start over with each customer_name??

Working in Access 2007 with SQL code builder.  Would be great if solution is compatible with Access.

Sorry for the length.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about another correlated subquery? Save you Query, say as Query1 (you probably want to remove the `ORDER BY` clause from this intermediate Query -- only need to sort the final resultset):

```
SELECT Q1.customer_name, Q1.order_date, Q1.price, 
       (
        SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
          FROM MyQuery AS Q2
         WHERE Q2.customer_name = Q1.customer_name
               AND Q2.order_date < Q1.order_date
       ) AS pivot_id
  FROM MyQuery AS Q1;
```

Comment: Few issues:
-VERY slow. 
-Assigns the same number to any orders with the same price, which happens frequently.  Looking at the data set example above, Company B had two purchases on feb 1 2009, both purchases are assigned a pivot_id of 1.

With some modifications, still slow, but works!  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the Access database engine isn't well optimized for correlated subqueries :( Consider re-writing your original query using TOP 5 to eliminate the *that* correlated subquery.